# IIS 8.5 not using applicationHost.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8, applicationhost

Using Windows server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.9600.16384
I wanted to change some config options for the IIS because i have a slow first load issue.

All documents i can find tell me that i should edit " C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config ". But i'm fairly certain that this isn't the config file used by the IIS. The file still contains older application pools/websites and is missing newer ones. Also when i make a change in the IIS interface this doens't change the config file.

Any thoughts on what might be happening here ?

Answer (score 4):

Exact same problem here, but finally found the answer: [Applicationhost.config not showing changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641621/applicationhost-config-not-showing-changes)! Unbelievable but true answer: *Notepad++* does not open the actual version of `applicationHost.config`. Restart IIS Manager, download and install [*Notepad2 x64*](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) and everything should work as expected.