# In IIS 8.5 is there a way of setting the ConnectionTimeout limit in web.config?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

In IIS 8.5 is there a way of setting the ConnectionTimeout limit in web.config?

I can see how you would set this at the Website level (either through the IIS Manager GUI or via settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) but would like to set it at the application level i.e. via web.config if possible.

I am aware of the web.config executionTimeout setting (i.e. `httpRuntime executionTimeout="100"`): and so was hoping there might be something similar for connectionTimeout.

Comment: Microsoft decided that many settings are `applicationHost.config` only, so you won't be able to set such in `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [per site limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits) from applicationHost.config, which would look like this:

```
<sites>
   <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
      <application path="/">
         <virtualDirectory path="/"
            physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
      </application>
      <bindings>
         <binding protocol="http"
            bindingInformation="*:80:" />
      </bindings>
     <limits maxBandwidth="65536"
         maxConnections="1024"
         connectionTimeout="00:01:00" />
   </site>
</sites>
```

(example taken from Microsoft docs)

If you execute the below `appcmd` during deployment you would get the same effect, but you cant use web.config to manage this value.

`appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites "/[name='Default Web Site'].limits.connectionTimeout:00:01:00" /commit:apphost`

I would *strongly* suggest using appcmd.exe to update these values rather than editing the XML directly (the 32 or 64 ["bit-ness" of your editor makes a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641621/applicationhost-config-not-showing-changes)!).

Answer (score 0):

These settings are managed by the applicationhost.config file. so you have to manually change it. and it is not a recommended way to modify the applicationhost file manually. it may break your other configuration.

you could use iis manager GUI or you can use the below commands:

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='sitename'].limits.connectionTimeout:"00:03:00"  /commit:apphost
```

or

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='testiis']/limits" -name "connectionTimeout" -value "00:03:00"
```